# What does the "++" operator do on a "char *"?

Tags: c, pointers, char, operators

In the following function:

```
double dict(const char *str1, const char *str2) {
```

There is the following:

```
if (strlen(str1) != 0 && strlen(str2) != 0)
    while (prefix_length < 3 && equal(*str1++, *str2++)) prefix_length++;
```

What does the operator `++` do in `*str1++` and `*str2++`?

Comment: Incrementing a pointer makes it point to the next object in memory.

Comment: Note: in expression `*(str++);` , parenthesis are redundant because precedence of `++` is higher then `*` deference operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `++` operator in `*str++` increments the pointer (not the thing pointed at).

```
(*str)++;   /* Increment the character pointed at by str */
 *str++;    /* Increment the pointer in str */
*(str++);   /* Increment the pointer in str - the same, but verbose */
```

There are two very different operations shown (one of them shown using two different but equivalent notations), though they both return the character that `str` pointed at before the increment occurs.  This is a consequence of the precedence rules in the standard — [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2) like `++` have higher precedence than [unary (prefix) operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3) like `*` unless parentheses are used to alter this.

Answer (score 2):

When you read or write to `*str1++`, the normal rules for postfix increment are applied.  That is:

1. The pointer is incremented to the next address
2. The previous pointer value is returned

At that stage you dereference the pointer value (which is the value prior to incrementing) and use the value it points to.

Answer (score 1):

`*str1++` means first use the value pointed by `str1` and then increment `str1`.

```
char arr[] = "meow";
char ch;

char *str = arr;

ch = *str++;    // ch = *(str++) both does same
```

After executing the statement above:

1. `ch` will contain `'m'`;
2. `str` will point to the address of `arr[1]`.

Comment: *cough* operator precedence *cough*

Comment: In practice, the pointer will be dereferenced and then incremented, perhaps that's what VoidPointer meant?

Comment: Yes @Nobilis, I meant the same.

Comment: @DennisMeng I think both `*` and `++` have same precedence. Associates from `right to left`

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you said; the first time I read I thought you were implying that `*str++` was the same as `(*str)++` (which we both know is wrong), but I see that you've clarified what you said.

Answer (score 0):

in `C` (and some derived languages) the `char` type is also a `number` type (a small one that can contains 256 different values), so you can do arithmetic operations on it, like addition (`+2`), increment (`++`) and so on.

in this case, the `++` operator doesn't increment the char but the pointer to this char.

`*str2++` returns the next address of the pointer to `str2`